# Can an Alexa Skill activate an Alexa voice command?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Can an Alexa Skill activate an Alexa command such as "call Frank"?

This currently can be done in an Alexa Routine with a Custom Action

Answer (score 0):

Currently automatic skill invocation is not supported. In order to use an Alexa skill, users must first enable it either via voice, routines or Reminders API.

Comment: I'm asking about an Alexa Skill being able to invoke an Alexa Voice command